# No strings Minimist Node JS

Tags: node.js, minimist

With Minimist what is used to write out a sentence like this?

`Name: Lea; Age: 22; Address: UserAdress`

So far I have tried with --name and --a. Hard to find information imo

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(0, 2))
console.log(process.argv.join());
```

```
node index.js --name=Lea -a 22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
const sentence = `Name: ${argv['name']}; Age: ${argv['age']}; Address: ${argv['address']}`
console.log(sentence)
```

On doing

```
$ node index.js --name=Lea --age=22 --address=UserAdress
```

Output:

> Name: Lea; Age: 22; Address: UserAdress

Further validations can be added on the arguments.

Comment: Yes that's it. Cheers thanks for your help